# Sql Location_of_2nd_Max_Logins logic

Tags: python, mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have a dataset like this I want to solve by using pandas series and get the output of user_id, last login date, lost login location, most frequent login location, and most frequent 2nd login location

```
event_name  event_date  user_id     user_city   user_state

exit_click  06-09-2021  10795552    Kayamkulam  Kerala
exit_click  06-09-2021  11129909    Tiruppur    Tamil Nadu
exit_click  06-09-2021  11028532    Thrissur    Kerala
exit_click  06-09-2021  5701734     Thrissur    Kerala
exit_click  06-09-2021  13178561    Navi Mumbai Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  4631431     Madurai     Tamil Nadu
exit_click  06-09-2021  4243309     Thane       Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  12934603    SriperumbudurTamil Nadu
exit_click  06-09-2021  12757354    Ghaziabad    Uttar Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  12504154    Kalyan       Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  12530698    Ulhasnagar   Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  12360310    Beed         Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  11431196    Udaipur      Rajasthan
exit_click  06-09-2021  13166134    VisakhapatnamAndhra Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  2136420     Rudrapur     Uttarakhand
exit_click  06-09-2021  9494724     Payyanur     Kerala
exit_click  06-09-2021  12396316    Baddi        Himachal Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  10249015    Bhopal       Madhya Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  10724140    Pathanamthitta  Kerala
exit_click  06-09-2021  9986130     Puducherry   Puducherry
exit_click  06-09-2021  7229405     Patiala      Punjab
exit_click  06-09-2021  7006354     Guntur       Andhra Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  8061789     Mehsana      Gujarat
exit_click  06-09-2021  9341808     Bhopal       Madhya Pradesh
exit_click  06-09-2021  9379141     Navi Mumbai  Maharashtra
exit_click  06-09-2021  6157171     Rohtak       Haryana
exit_click  06-09-2021  13124731    Khammam      Telangana
exit_click  06-09-2021  13172076    Amravati     Maharashtra
```

The output show look like this

```
user_id | Last_date | most Location   | Location of  | Location on        |
        |  of_login | of Latest Login | Max Logins   | Second Most Logins |
        |           |                 |              |                    |
3       |06=09-2021 |Gurgaon          | Thane        | Gurgaon            |
```

So I Tried this logic

```
select bq.user_id as user_id, 
bq.event_date as Date_of_Last_Login,
bq.user_city as Location_of_Latest_Login,
max(user_city) as Location_of_Max_Logins from bq 

group by user_id
order by event_date DESC ;
```

and I got the result for

Date_of_Last_Login,

Location_of_Latest_Login,

Location_of_Max_Logins

But I could not find the logic for the
Location_of_2nd_Max_Logins

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a single aggregation.  What you can do is use aggregation by city and user and enumerate the results -- once by count and once by recency.  Then aggregate again at the user level:

```
select user_id, max(login_date) as max_login_date,
       max(case when seqnum_ed = 1 then user_city end) as max_login_date_city,
       max(case when seqnum_cnt = 1 then user_city end) as max_login_city,
       max(case when seqnum_cnt = 2 then user_city end) as max_2_login_city
from (select bq.user_id, bq.user_city,
             count(*) as num_logins,
             max(event_date) as max_login_date,
             row_number() over (partition by bq.user_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by bq.user_id order by max(event_date) desc) as seqnum_ed
      from bq 
      group by user_id
     ) u
group by user_id;
```